# ActionMailer, sending out an email with a background image

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am attempting to send out an HTML e-mail that's essentially just one giant image to our users. So far, I haven't tried anything fancy. My view looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
         background-image: url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/image.png');
         background-repeat: repeat-y no-repeat;
         background-color: #333;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not entirely concerned about having this work on ALL mail clients, but the major ones would be great. When I send this e-mail out using ActionMailer, I just get an empty message. Doesn't look like the image is getting applied, at least in gmail web client.

Any advice would be great. I also hope to make the entire image clickable which goes to an iTunes store link, but I'll get to that part when I get the image to show up.

Comment: Whats the name of your file? Does your mailer work with text only?

Comment: ActionMailer works with both text and text/html.

Comment: I'm sure it does. Does the email template send when you're using just text?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your file is accessible to public? Try accessing the URL directly.
If not, you have to mark it as publicly accessible in your amazon bucket.

Here is a snippet from one of our mailers with an image on S3 (.erb file), and it works fine:

```
Dear <b><%= @card.first_name %></b>,
<br/><br/>
Thank you for being a member with us since <strong><%= @card.start_date.strftime("%d %b %Y") %></strong>.
<br/><br/>

 ...

 Warm Regards,
 <br/>
Team MyCompany
<br/><br/>
<% if Settings.show_banner_image_in_email %>
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <a href="<%= Settings.website_url %>">
      <img src="http://cdn2.mywebsite.com/images/EmailFooterBanner.jpg" width="590px" height="118px" />
    </a>
  </div>
<% end %>

<b>Happy to Help!</b>
<br/>Voice: 23424234242342
<br/>E-mail: <a href="mailto:customercare@mywebsite.com">customercare@mywebsite.com</a>
<br/>Web: <a href="<%= Settings.website_url %>"><%= Settings.website_url %></a>
<br/>
```

EDIT:
If your model in app/mailers is called **UserMailer**, you have to store your mailer view in a folder called "**user_mailer**" under views. That's when it gets picked up.

Comment: It's definitely accessible to the public, verified it several times.

Comment: Edited my original answer, to mention that the view has to be stored in a specific folder under views. Check if that solves the problem. I simulated your problem on mine, and the view in this folder got picked up by ActionMailer.

Answer (score 0):

All css in email should be inline. Consider using a gem like `premailer` to help inline it.

https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails3